# How do I place tabbar above the toolbar in PyQt5?

Tags: python, pyqt5

I have been working on a Web Browser in PyQt5 and what I'm trying to do is place the tab bar with the tabs above the toolbar. Chrome, Edge and Firefox all have this but is there a way to place the tab bar above the toolbar? If there is a way, that would be very helpful.

This is the entire app's source code:

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets, QtWebEngineWidgets
from operator import iconcat
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QShortcut, QApplication, QWizard, QTabWidget, QWidget, QPushButton, QToolButton, QTabBar, QApplication
from PyQt5.QtCore import *
from PyQt5.QtGui import *
from PyQt5.QtGui import QFont, QFontDatabase
from PyQt5.QtWebEngineWidgets import *
from PyQt5.QtCore import QUrl
from PyQt5.QtNetwork import *
from PyQt5.QtPrintSupport import *
import sys
import os


class MainWindow(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(MainWindow, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.tabs = QTabWidget()
        self.tabs.setDocumentMode(True)
        self.tabs.tabBarClicked.connect(self.tab_open_doubleclick)
        self.tabs.currentChanged.connect(self.current_tab_changed)
        self.tabs.setTabsClosable(True)
        self.tabs.tabCloseRequested.connect(self.close_current_tab)
        self.setStyleSheet('''
        QTabBar::tab {
            color: #000;
            padding: 5px;
            border-top-left-radius: 10px;
            border-top-right-radius: 10px;
            width: 150px;
        }
        QTabBar::tab:selected {
            background: white;
        }
        ''')
        self.setCentralWidget(self.tabs)

        self.status = QStatusBar()
        self.setStatusBar(self.status)

        self.navtb = QToolBar("Navigation", movable=False)
        self.navtb.setStyleSheet("background-color: white;"
                                 "height : 50px;"
        )
        self.navtb.setFixedHeight(50)
        self.addToolBar(self.navtb)

        BackBtn = QPushButton()
        BackBtn.setText("←")
        self.navtb.addWidget(BackBtn)
        BackBtn.clicked.connect(lambda:self.tabs.currentWidget().back()) 
        BackBtn.setFont(QFont('Arial', 13))
        BackBtn.setStyleSheet("QPushButton"
                             "{"
                             "background-color : #FFFFFF;"
                             "border-top-left-radius : 20px;"
                             "border-top-right-radius : 20px; "
                             "border-bottom-left-radius : 20px; "
                             "border-bottom-right-radius : 20px;"
                             "width: 40px;"
                             "height: 40px;"
                             "}"
                             "QPushButton::hover"
                             "{"
                             "background-color : #EEEEEE;"
                             "}"
                             "QPushButton::pressed"
                             "{"
                             "background-color : #DDDDDD;"
                             "}"
                             )
  
        BackBtn.show()

        self.placeholderspace = QLabel()    
        self.navtb.addWidget(self.placeholderspace)

        ForBtn = QPushButton()
        ForBtn.setText("→")
        self.navtb.addWidget(ForBtn)
        ForBtn.clicked.connect(lambda:self.tabs.currentWidget().forward()) 
        ForBtn.setFont(QFont('Arial', 13))
        ForBtn.setStyleSheet("QPushButton"
                             "{"
                             "background-color : #FFFFFF;"
                             "border-top-left-radius : 20px;"
                             "border-top-right-radius : 20px; "
                             "border-bottom-left-radius : 20px; "
                             "border-bottom-right-radius : 20px;"
                             "width: 40px;"
                             "height: 40px;"
                             "}"
                             "QPushButton::hover"
                             "{"
                             "background-color : #EEEEEE;"
                             "}"
                             "QPushButton::pressed"
                             "{"
                             "background-color : #DDDDDD;"
                             "}"
                             )
  
        ForBtn.show()

        self.placeholderspace2 = QLabel()   
        self.navtb.addWidget(self.placeholderspace2)

        RelBtn = QPushButton()
        RelBtn.setText("⟳")
        self.navtb.addWidget(RelBtn)
        RelBtn.clicked.connect(lambda:self.tabs.currentWidget().reload()) 
        RelBtn.setFont(QFont('Arial', 13))
        RelBtn.setStyleSheet("QPushButton"
                             "{"
                             "background-color : #FFFFFF;"
                             "border-top-left-radius : 20px;"
                             "border-top-right-radius : 20px; "
                             "border-bottom-left-radius : 20px; "
                             "border-bottom-right-radius : 20px;"
                             "width: 40px;"
                             "height: 40px;"
                             "}"
                             "QPushButton::hover"
                             "{"
                             "background-color : #EEEEEE;"
                             "}"
                             "QPushButton::pressed"
                             "{"
                             "background-color : #DDDDDD;"
                             "}"
                             )
  
        RelBtn.show()

        self.placeholderspace3 = QLabel()   
        self.navtb.addWidget(self.placeholderspace3)

        HomeBtn = QPushButton()
        HomeBtn.setText("⌂")
        self.navtb.addWidget(HomeBtn)
        HomeBtn.clicked.connect(self.navigate_home) 
        HomeBtn.setFont(QFont('Arial', 13))
        HomeBtn.setStyleSheet("QPushButton"
                             "{"
                             "background-color : #FFFFFF;"
                             "border-top-left-radius : 20px;"
                             "border-top-right-radius : 20px; "
                             "border-bottom-left-radius : 20px; "
                             "border-bottom-right-radius : 20px;"
                             "width: 40px;"
                             "height: 40px;"
                             "}"
                             "QPushButton::hover"
                             "{"
                             "background-color : #EEEEEE;"
                             "}"
                             "QPushButton::pressed"
                             "{"
                             "background-color : #DDDDDD;"
                             "}"
                             )
  
        HomeBtn.show()

        self.placeholderspace4 = QLabel()   
        self.navtb.addWidget(self.placeholderspace4)

        QFontDatabase.addApplicationFont("Montserrat.tff")
        font = QFont("Arial", 12)
        self.urlBar = QLineEdit()
        self.urlBar.setStyleSheet( "border-top-left-radius : 15px;"
                                   "border-top-right-radius : 15px; "
                                   "border-bottom-left-radius : 15px; "
                                   "border-bottom-right-radius : 15px;"
                                   "background-color : #EEEEEE;"
                                   "padding-left : 20px;"
                                   "padding-right : 20px;"
                                   "height : 30px;"
                                )
        self.urlBar.setFont(font)
        self.urlBar.returnPressed.connect(self.navigate_to_url)
        self.urlBar.setPlaceholderText('Type URL of the Website')
        self.navtb.addWidget(self.urlBar)

        self.placeholderspace5 = QLabel()
        self.navtb.addWidget(self.placeholderspace5)

        StopBtn = QPushButton()
        StopBtn.setText("x")
        self.navtb.addWidget(StopBtn)
        StopBtn.clicked.connect(lambda:self.tabs.currentWidget().stop()) 
        StopBtn.setFont(QFont('Arial', 10))
        StopBtn.setStyleSheet("QPushButton"
                             "{"
                             "background-color : #FFFFFF;"
                             "border-top-left-radius : 20px;"
                             "border-top-right-radius : 20px; "
                             "border-bottom-left-radius : 20px; "
                             "border-bottom-right-radius : 20px;"
                             "width: 40px;"
                             "height: 40px;"
                             "}"
                             "QPushButton::hover"
                             "{"
                             "background-color : #EEEEEE;"
                             "}"
                             "QPushButton::pressed"
                             "{"
                             "background-color : #DDDDDD;"
                             "}"
                             )
  
        StopBtn.show()

        self.placeholderspace6 = QLabel()   
        self.navtb.addWidget(self.placeholderspace6)

        KCBtn = QPushButton()
        KCBtn.setText("About Us")
        self.navtb.addWidget(KCBtn)
        KCBtn.clicked.connect(self.navigate_koala) 
        KCBtn.setFont(QFont('Arial', 10))
        KCBtn.setStyleSheet("QPushButton"
                             "{"
                             "background-color : #FFFFFF;"
                             "border-top-left-radius : 20px;"
                             "border-top-right-radius : 20px; "
                             "border-bottom-left-radius : 20px; "
                             "border-bottom-right-radius : 20px;"
                             "width: 100px;"
                             "height: 40px;"
                             "}"
                             "QPushButton::hover"
                             "{"
                             "background-color : #EEEEEE;"
                             "}"
                             "QPushButton::pressed"
                             "{"
                             "background-color : #DDDDDD;"
                             "}"
                             )
  
        KCBtn.show()

        self.add_new_tab(QUrl('file:///C:/Users/mayan/Desktop/Koala%20Software/Koala_SpaceShip_(Python_ED)/google.html'), 'homepage')
        self.show()
        self.setWindowTitle('Khanda SpaceShip New Tab')
        self.setWindowIcon(QIcon('icon.ico'))
        self.showMaximized()

    def add_new_tab(self, qurl=None, label = "Khanda SpaceShip"):
        if qurl is None:
            qurl = QUrl('file:///C:/Users/mayan/Desktop/Koala%20Software/Koala_SpaceShip_(Python_ED)/google.html')

        browser = QWebEngineView()
        browser.settings().setAttribute(
            QWebEngineSettings.FullScreenSupportEnabled, True
        )
        browser.setUrl(qurl)

        i= self.tabs.addTab(browser, label)
        self.tabs.setCurrentIndex(i)

        browser.urlChanged.connect(lambda qurl, browser = browser : self.update_urlbar(qurl, browser))

        browser.loadFinished.connect(lambda _, i= i, browser = browser : self.tabs.setTabText(i, browser.page().title()))

        browser.page().fullScreenRequested.connect(
            lambda request, browser=browser: self.handle_fullscreen_requested(
                request, browser
            )
        )


        self.tabs.setTabIcon(i, browser.icon())
        browser.iconChanged.connect(lambda icon, browser=browser: self.update_icon(browser, icon))

    def handle_fullscreen_requested(self, request, browser):
        request.accept()

        if request.toggleOn():
            self.showFullScreen()
            self.statusBar().hide()
            self.navtb.hide()
            self.tabs.tabBar().hide()
        else:
            self.showNormal()
            self.statusBar().show()
            self.navtb.show()
            self.tabs.tabBar().show()

    def tab_open_doubleclick(self, i):

        if i == -1:
            self.add_new_tab()

    def current_tab_changed(self, i):
        qurl = self.tabs.currentWidget().url()
        self.update_urlbar(qurl, self.tabs.currentWidget())
        self.update_title(self.tabs.currentWidget())

    def close_current_tab(self, i):
        if self.tabs.count() < 1:
            return
        page = self.tabs.widget(i)
        self.tabs.removeTab(i)
        page.deleteLater()

    def update_icon(self, browser, icon):
        index = self.tabs.indexOf(browser)
        self.tabs.setTabIcon(index, icon)

    def update_title(self, browser):
        if browser != self.tabs.currentWidget():
            return

        title = self.tabs.currentWidget().page().title()
        self.setWindowTitle("% s - Khanda SpaceShip" % title)

    def navigate_home(self):
        self.tabs.currentWidget().setUrl(QUrl("file:///C:/Users/mayan/Desktop/Koala%20Software/Koala_SpaceShip_(Python_ED)/google.html"))

    def navigate_koala(self):
        self.tabs.currentWidget().setUrl(QUrl("https://mayankadi99.github.io/khanda.github.io/index.html"))

    def navigate_to_url(self):
        q = QUrl(self.urlBar.text())
        if q.scheme() == "":
            q.setScheme("https")
        self.tabs.currentWidget().setUrl(q)

    def update_urlbar(self, q, browser = None):
        if browser != self.tabs.currentWidget():
            return
        
        self.urlBar.setText(q.toString())
        self.urlBar.setCursorPosition(0)



app = QApplication(sys.argv)
app.setApplicationName("Khanda SpaceShip")
app.setOrganizationName("Khanda Corparation")
app.setOrganizationDomain("mkhanda.com")
window  = MainWindow()
mw = MainWindow()
mw.show()
sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: Create a widget that subclasses QWidget and add a toolbar at the top of the widget, then every time you create a new tab use your subclass as the new tab widget and it will always have a toolbar

Comment: Don't use a QMainWindow. Create your own QWidget subclass and use [QTabBar](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtabbar.html), [QToolBar](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtoolbar.html), and [QStackedWidget](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qstackedwidget.html).